# MySQL query optimization prestashop

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, timezone, prestashop

I'm currently writing an SQL statement for fetching timezone for a specific country in a Prestashop setup database. The tables I'm using are:

- **ps_timezone**: The time zone (Canada/Atlantic, America/Adak, etc.)
- **ps_country_lang**: Name of the country (canada, united state, france, etc.)
- **ps_country**: country table (I used it since I know the country, but I want to know its zone).
- **ps_zone**: zone (america, europe, asia, etc)

And I wrote the following query (id_country =4 is canada):

```
SELECT tz.id_timezone, tz.name FROM ps_timezone tz WHERE tz.name LIKE CONCAT((SELECT cl.name FROM ps_country_lang cl WHERE cl.id_country=4 and cl.id_lang = 1) ,'%') OR tz.name LIKE CONCAT((SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(z.name, 'Europe') > 0 THEN 'Europe' WHEN INSTR(z.name, 'America') > 0 THEN 'America' ELSE z.name END as zone_name FROM ps_zone z JOIN ps_country c ON z.id_zone = c.id_zone WHERE c.id_country =4), '%') ORDER BY CASE WHEN tz.name LIKE CONCAT((SELECT cl.name FROM ps_country_lang cl WHERE cl.id_country=4 and cl.id_lang = 1) ,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, tz.name ASC;
```

The query is working fine, yet I would like seniors' adviced regarding optimization for my personal improvement and culture.

First, I'm using a LIKE to verify whether the timezone starts with the country name:

```
tz.name LIKE CONCAT((SELECT cl.name FROM ps_country_lang cl WHERE cl.id_country=4 and cl.id_lang = 1) ,'%')
```

Or the zone name:

```
tz.name LIKE CONCAT((SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(z.name, 'Europe') > 0 THEN 'Europe' WHEN INSTR(z.name, 'America') > 0 THEN 'America' ELSE z.name END as zone_name FROM ps_zone z JOIN ps_country c ON z.id_zone = c.id_zone WHERE c.id_country =4), '%')
```

I'm suspecting that the LIKE keyword is not the most performant one...would it be more performant to extract the first part of the timezone and compare it directly like this:

```
WHERE LEFT(tz.name, INSTR(tz.name, "/") - 1) = (SELECT cl.name FROM ps_country_lang cl WHERE cl.id_country=4 and cl.id_lang = 1)
```

Second, I'm using a SELECT in the ORDER BY so the timezone with the country name are presented first.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN tz.name LIKE CONCAT((SELECT cl.name FROM ps_country_lang cl WHERE cl.id_country=4 and cl.id_lang = 1) ,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, tz.name ASC
```

Of course, it is an esthetic matter, yet I'm worrying about performance issues. Would the query be run only once since it is using fixed values (I know the country id before sending the query to the database and the language should always 1 for english) or will it run for each row?

Moreover, I don't like it much since I have the exact same subquery both in the WHERE clause and the ORDER BY clauses. I cannot use an alias from the SELECT clause as the WHERE clause is executed first (anyway it would force me to return a row uselessly).

Of course, the best course of doing things would be for me to exclude timezone with continent name if I have timezone for the country...

I'm conscious those are no easy questions, yet think these are interesting matter for many juniors, as myself, serious about learning proper programming.

Thank you,

Jonathan Parent-Lévesque from Montreal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simplify this query by taking advantage of the [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) PHP component introduced in PHP 5.2 which returns timezone identifiers for a given ISO 3166-1 country code (e.g. "CA" for Canada).

Example:

```
<?php

$country_iso_code = 'CA';
$timezone = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, $country_iso_code);

echo $timezone[0]; /* Multiple timezones per country, get the 1st one */
```

Comment: If it was my own coding, I would had used that solution for sure, but prestashop is an ecommerce platform on which developers can add custom modules.

My personal experience in data importing from my Boss' other software (GEM-CAR) is that a slight change/omission in the data structure causes Prestashop not to work (by example, user account don't work if you put an empty string as family names).

This is why I'm using this complicated query to fetch prestashop included timezone.

But, I will gladly consider that solution for my personal projects though.

Thank you

Comment: In PrestaShop, we built the ps_timezone MySQL table for the sole prupose of properly setting the date_default_timezone_set() function in config/config.inc.php. This table is a pure reflection of the DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() which did not exist at that time and is not linked to Country or Zones. That's why I'd suggest to use the DateTimeZone PHP class and have a completely separated code, apart from the PrestaShop core.